# How can use MediaMetadataRetriever().setDataSource() while MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA is deprecated to get the path

Tags: android, media, mediametadataretriever

I'm trying to get all audio files of an android device in addition to cover image of each one of them. MediaMetadataRetriever().setDataSource() should take a path but MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA that provides path is deprecated. I tried this but I take IllegalArgumentException. I'm not sure if I'm doing it in the right way or not by the way. This is the code:

```
import android.content.ContentUris
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.provider.MediaStore

fun getAllAudioFromDevice(context: Context): List<AudioModel> {
    val tempAudioList: MutableList<AudioModel> = ArrayList()
    val projection =
        arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
    val c: Cursor? =
        context.contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null)

    if (c != null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            val mmr = android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever()
            val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, c.getLong(0))

            mmr.setDataSource(contentUri.path)

            val coverImage = mmr.embeddedPicture
            val audioModel = AudioModel(contentUri, c.getString(1), c.getString(2), c.getString(3), coverImage)
            tempAudioList.add(audioModel)
        }
        c.close()
    }
    return tempAudioList
}
```

Comment: What do you have in mind that should happen if you call setDataSource()?

Comment: I'm just trying to implement a code in answer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420193/how-to-get-album-art-from-a-song-file-in-android) by Hiren Jungi, then I noticed the code in [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) to get audio files which is not using MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA. but it seems I need this to get the image of a song. @ blackapps

Comment: I run the code by deprecated MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA with no problem in getting the image. @blackapps

Comment: You did not give answer to my question. And please dont post links.

Comment: I don't know what should happen. Nothing in my mind about this. @blackapps

Comment: Then why do you wanna use this function? Look at the title of your post.

Comment: As I mentioned I want to take the image of a song in the way of a link I posted above. And this is a function used there. I think it's not that unclear. If there is better way please help me find it. Thanks in advance. @blackapps

Comment: That all still does not tell us why you wanna use this function.

Comment: I cannot figure out what is your expected answer. Is this chat leading us to anywhere?@blackapps